Internal HTTPS links not working when deployed React app to VPS
I build a React app locally
that has a simple login page, MongoDB on Cloud Atlas (remote) and a bunch of internal links once user is logged in like dashboard, analytics and other stuff).
Now I want to deploy it on VPS server (Ubuntu) and I set up the SSL all good but now I have to change all internal links from localhost:3000 as example to websitename.com (with https in front of course).
I am not sure how to handle this because once I do all that transition the login stops working (it authenticates me no matter what characters I put, it bypasses basically) and once I am inside there is no data or connection to the Node.js server (for retrieving analytics data from DB).
This is Nginx conf file.
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name vps-ipaddress mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

    ssl_certificate /pathtocertificate/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /pathtocertificate/privkey.pem;

    location /login {
        proxy_pass http://vps-ipaddress:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # Additional SSL parameters for proxy
        proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        proxy_ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        proxy_ssl_verify off;  # Only use this for testing, not in production
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://vps-ipaddress:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

and this is my login component (a part of it)
    const Login = ({ onLogin }) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("https://mywebsite.com/login", {
        username,
        password,
      });
      localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token);
      onLogin();
      navigate("/dashboard");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error during login:", err);
      setError(err.response?.data?.error || "Error during login");
    }
  };

  return (
    <PageContainer>
      <FormContainer>
        <FormTitle>Login</FormTitle>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <FormField>
            <Label>Username</Label>
            <Input
              type="text"
              value={username}
              onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </FormField>
          <FormField>
            <Label>Password</Label>
            <Input
              type="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </FormField>
          {error && <ErrorMessage>{error}</ErrorMessage>}
          <Button type="submit">Login</Button>
        </form>
        <SwitchContainer>
          <Link to="/register">Don't have an account? Register</Link>
        </SwitchContainer>
      </FormContainer>
    </PageContainer>
  );
};


nginx is a web server, not a DNS server.
